# Bash : extracting date from file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I am new to bash and I have a file like this :

```
2012-11-22 11:36:55,909 1353551815756 1353551815909 0 true myapi 10 203051 203051:ShopDb:ShopDb
2012-11-22 11:37:00,292 1353551820146 1353551820292 0 true myapi 10 201897 201897:ShopDb:ShopDb
2012-11-22 11:38:01,824 1353551881672 1353551881824 0 true myapi 10 203051 203051:ShopDb:ShopDb
```

In a loop,line I want to extract date part (2012-11-22 11:36:55) convert to time-stamp and assign to a variable(or simply dis
How to achieve this in bash ?

Comment: what do you mean by "convert to time-stamp"? Do you mean convert to seconds since the epoch or just strip out the non-digits or something else? Posting the expected output for your posted input would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ while IFS=" ," read f1 f2 f3
> do
>  echo $f1 $f2
> done < file
2012-11-22 11:36:55
2012-11-22 11:37:00
2012-11-22 11:38:01
```

By setting the IFS to a space and comma makes it easy to extract the 1st 2 fields in the while loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use date command, as one of the way to do it.

```
while IFS=, read x y; do
    date --date "$x" +%s
done < file.txt
```

`+%s` converts it to the timestamp as you want.

Comment: useless use of both cat and cut. `while IFS=, read -r x y; do...; done < file.txt` would do the whole job.

Comment: ^^ Yes, you are right... I wanted to highlight use of date command to do the job, instead of awk... editing the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GNU awk` to get the timestamps and capture them using a bash array:

```
array=($(awk -F, '{ print mktime(gensub(/[:-]/," ","g",$1))}' file.txt))
```

Then you can iterate through them:

```
for i in "${array[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

Results:

```
1353548215
1353548220
1353548281
```

Or simply select one to print; for example, to echo the second element:

```
echo "${array[1]}"
```

Results:

```
1353548220
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will extract the date for you:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ ,]"; OFS=" ";} {print $1, $2}' input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `cut` command:

```
cut -c1-19 file
```

This will extract characters 1 through to 19 from each line.

To just retrieve the first line:

```
head -n 1 file | cut -c1-19
```

and to assign that to a bash variable:

```
myTime=$(head -n 1 file | cut -c1-19)
```